# Converting a Maven project to Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

I was able to use Gradle's init plugin to export most of the contents of the POM (all dependencies) to the `build.gradle` file. However the the `<build>` section was not imported into the `build.gradle`. The below was not imported.

E.g.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>my-group-id.myproject-bundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please let me know how this can be imported into the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Did you see this part of the manual? http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/osgi_plugin.html

Comment: oh, chapter 66 - how could anyone have missed that?