# use maven's pom.xml for gradle build dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, pom.xml

My question is fairly simple. I have a maven java project and I would like to build it with gradle. currently I have a `pom.xml` file where I'm managing dependencies, *as well as* a `build.gradle` file where I list each of these dependencies as:

```
// build.gradle file:
dependencies {
     compile (
        <some groupId>:<some artifactId>:<some version>,
        etc.
    )
}
```

I'd really like to avoid this redundancy but I do not see any way to have the `build.gradle` file integrate `pom.xml` into it's dependencies. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648037/converting-a-maven-project-to-gradle?rq=1

Comment: Why do you need to maintain both? Pick one and move forward.

Comment: If you **really** need to use both build tools, but want to maintain the dependencies in your `pom.xml`, you can implement the required functionality to read the dependencies in Groovy and use it in your Gradle script (you can even write a plugin). The `pom.xml` file is in XML format, so it should be easy to parse it.

Answer (score 3):

You just maintain your pom.xml with all your latest dependencies. At last run `>gradle init` command to convert your latest pom into build.gradle. So this will copy all dependencies from pom.xml file to build.gragle.

sample - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html#migmvn:automatic_conversion